# Which tool for generating UML Entity-Relationship Diagrams using text?

Tags: uml, erd, entity-relationship

Which tool [for any OS... or even web] can I use to generate UML Entity-Relationship diagrams from text?

Thinking something along the lines of http://yuml.me/, really quick to write up.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Are you aware that Entity-Relationship diagrams is not a kind of UML diagram right? ER is a different modeling language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of all textual UML tools (AFAIK) can be found [here](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual)

Answer (score 1):

I liked these two

1. [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/).
   It's easy and you have option to save diagrams to google drive and dropbox
2. [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/)

Comment: draw.io is cool enough, but I'm just not seeing any text-based tools. These are both visual drag-and-drop tools.